# could not set jquery ui dialog min-width

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have been trying to use jquery  ui dialog. But I m not able to set the minimum width and height. 
Here is my code

```
 var options={
                modal: true,
                title:headertext,
                minHeight:125,
                minWidth:520,
                maxWidth:1000,
                maxHeight:1000,
                dialogClass:"sfFormwrapper"};
            $('#'+popupid ).dialog(options);
```

But in the browser it is rendered as

```
height:auto ; width:520px
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You seem to be under the impression that the `minWidth`, `minHeight`, `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` options map directly to `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width` and `max-height` CSS style rules, respectively. That's not actually the case.

The style rules in your question come from the widget element itself (the root of the tree, exposing the `ui-dialog` class). Note that the `minWidth` option translates to a `width` rule, which is actually dynamic: it's managed by the widget and will change as you resize the dialog.

In the same way, the original element augmented by the dialog widget has dynamic `width`, `height` and `min-height` rules applied.

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39A4U/) if you use the layout view of your browser's development tools, the widget does ensure that the total size of the dialog box (borders and title bar included) remains within the bounds you specified.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, minWidth/minHeight/etc limit [**user resizing**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-minWidth), not grow/shrink according to content. Per the site: *MinWidth: The minimum width to which the dialog can be resized, in pixels.* Am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 6):

Min/Max just control the minimum you can resize it.  If you want to set it to a certain height use height/width.   Also might want to pass the method name 'option' to your dialog() call.

```
 var options={
            modal: true,
            title:headertext,
            height: 500,
            minHeight:125,
            minWidth:520,
            maxWidth:1000,
            maxHeight:1000,
            dialogClass:"sfFormwrapper"};
 $('#'+popupid ).dialog('option', options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

`$('#'+popupid).dialog({ width:400, height:300, maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 500, minWidth: 300, minHeight: 200 });`

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer

```
$( "#info" ).dialog({
  draggable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  width: '40%',
  height: 450,
  modal: true 
});

$( ".info" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#info" ).dialog( "open" );
  $( ".ui-dialog").css({'min-width': '350px'});
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS!

```
.ui-widget-content {
min-width: 360px;
}
```

Or

min-width: 25%;